# Tools page - new tags not correctly aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

https://magento.stackexchange.com/tools looks like this ... FF 66.0.3

[image]

Can someone check pls?

Comment: Seems ,it has been fixed

Comment: No Amit, its not. Maybe browser related?

Comment: Still getting design issue?

Comment: @AmitBera Yes. Seems it displays 6 items per row w/o checking width. Is it correct for you? (30d stats)

Comment: This is due to the responsive design layout. We haven't updated all of the pages to be responsive yet and this is one of them. The plan is to make all pages responsive eventually. Apologies!

Comment: @Catija Thanx. Maybe want to add this as answer to accept/close?

Comment: I can, if you consider it an answer. :) It's definitely a bug that we'll be fixing eventually, I'm just not sure when. Just to double check. This view doesn't come up when I go to the link you have at the top. Is that the right link?

Comment: @Catija Of course its an answer :) You "eventually" want to fix it ... or not ... or not sure when. I can leave it open and its on you to close it when it is fixed ... or not. ;) Yes, it is the top right link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of the site redesign we made the network responsive - which means that the page scales to the width of your browser window with a max width. If your window is narrower, we adjust the center section to allow it all to fit without side scrolling. When we made this change, however, we weren't able to make every type of page responsive at the same time. Moderation pages like the Tools page are part of the pages we haven't touched yet.

We'll be fixing the rest of the pages over time to make them responsive. It's a pretty laborious process because there are so many different pages, some easier to make responsive than others. We're also trying to do this the "right" way. Rather than just making a page responsive, we're trying to update the page to be sure that it's doing what it needs to be doing and looks good and is actually usable.

Thanks for the report and for bearing with us while we go through this transition!